# Раскрывающийся свиток, пример использования

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Подскажите пожалуйста примеры сайтов или лучше сразу Js или css код для создания эффекта раскрывающихся свитка на сайте.

Без флеша, свиток представляет из себя некий div элемент который при клике должен плавно разворачиваться, но не просто в бок выезжать, а действительно разворачиваться.

Уже весь нет перерыл, можно нонечно использовать новые свойства CSS для трансформации объектов, но это не подходит так как мало где будет работать

Answer (score 1):

Наконец-то я увидел пример того, как сам не могу понять, как можно было такое не найти. Как-то не так ты искал.

Я вот так вот делал.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <h2>pSeven</h2>    <!-- this H2 would be the title of roll -->
    <div class="roll">    <!-- this div.roll would be collapsible -->
        <h3>Stable Release</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/assets/files/releases/pSeven-2.1-windows-installer.exe"><strong>pSeven 2.1 Final</strong> for Windows (any version)</a></li>
            <li><a href="/assets/files/releases/pSeven-2.1-linux-installer.run"><strong>pSeven 2.1 Final</strong> for Linux (32-bit system)</a></li>
            <li><a href="/assets/files/releases/pSeven-2.1-linux-x64-installer.run"><strong>pSeven 2.1 Final</strong> for Linux (64-bit system)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#content').find('h2+.roll').each(function(i, n)
    {
    var $h2 = $(this).prev();
    var $content = $(this).clone();
    var $roll = $('<section/>');
    $roll
        .addClass('roll-container')
        .append($h2.addClass('roll-caption'))
        .append($content.addClass('roll-content'));

    $(this).replaceWith($roll);
    if ((!$content.hasClass('open') && i > 0) || $content.hasClass('close'))
        {
        $content.animate({'height': 'toggle'}, 0);
        }
    else
        {
        $roll.addClass('roll-open');
        }

    $content.removeClass('open').removeClass('close');
    $h2.click(function()
        {
        if ($roll.hasClass('roll-open'))
            {
            $content.animate({'height': 'toggle'}, 200);  // !!!
            $roll.removeClass('roll-open');
            }
        else
            {
            $content.animate({'height': 'toggle'}, 200);  // !!!
            $roll.addClass('roll-open');
            }
        });
    });
```

CSS:

```
.roll-container > .roll-caption {
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #456;
    text-shadow: #eee 0px 1px 1px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    background: #edeeef;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition:     all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition:      all 0.3s ease;
    transition:         all 0.3s ease;

    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.roll-container > .roll-caption:hover {
    background: #789;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: #456 0px 1px 1px;

    -moz-box-shadow:    rgba(0,0,0,0.13) 0px 0px 3px,
                        #fff 0px 0px 100px 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.13) 0px 0px 3px,
                        #fff 0px 0px 100px 10px;
    box-shadow:         rgba(0,0,0,0.13) 0px 0px 3px,
                        #fff 0px 0px 100px 10px;
}

.roll-container > .roll-content {
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
    -moz-transition:    opacity 0.15s ease;
    -ms-transition:     opacity 0.15s ease;
    -o-transition:      opacity 0.15s ease;
    transition:         opacity 0.15s ease;
}
.roll-container.roll-open > .roll-content {
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:    opacity 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition:     opacity 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition:      opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition:         opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.roll-container > .roll-caption:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 20px;
    background: url('../images/roll-arrow.png') 0px 0px no-repeat;
}
.roll-container > .roll-caption:hover:after {
    background-position: -15px 0px;
}
.roll-container.roll-open > .roll-caption:after {
    background-position: -30px 0px;
}
.roll-container.roll-open > .roll-caption:hover:after {
    background-position: -45px 0px;
}
```

Comment: @Bars, вы забыли html-код в примере обернуть в

    <div id="container"></div>

Comment: Спасибо, только не `container`, a `content`.
Поправил.

Comment: Я имел в виду немного другое, вот примерно что мне нужно http://codepen.io/tribatar/pen/ozdxg
Но желательно минимум CSS и больше перенести на JS(jQuery), но пока кроме CSS трансформаций ни чего в голову не идет, а они работают далеко не везде